# What language is accepted by idris-proof-script-mode?

Tags: emacs, idris

In Emacs, with idris-mode 20200522.808, when I load the file using `C-c C-l`, I'm presented with a list of holes, and the message "Press the [P] buttons to solve the holes interactively in the prover."

The prover consists of two windows, `*idris-proof-obligations*` and `*idris-proof-script*`. But I can't figure out how this is supposed to work. I tried typing in the same sort of terms I would use in the command-line prover, like `` intro `{{x}} `` and `rewriteWith mylemma`, but when I type `M-n` to "advance", I got these error messages:

```
Prover error: (input):1:7:
  |
1 | intro ‘{{n}}
  |       ^
unexpected ’‘’
expecting end of input or name

Prover error: (input):1:8:
  |
1 | rewriteWith sym (fibAuxEq 0 1 n)
  |        ^
unexpected ’W’
expecting tactic
```

What should I be doing instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It accepts proof tactics in the language of [the old theorem prover](http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/guides/theorem-prover.html), which is deprecated.